# FreeIPA - remove user password

Tags: ldap, password, user-accounts, freeipa

I have created a user in FreeIPA. He has been assigned a password and SSH key. I want him to leave only SSH key.

Is there a way, how to remove password??

Answer (score 0):

You could set some random password, but if you don't want password login, disable it in your `sshd_config`.